# How to resize and position an image in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I can't figure out the rhyme or reason to how the Size and Position settings work for an OLE Object image in Crystal Reports.  I can get the width to change, but I am not sure how the units of measure work.

My Google-fu has been weak on this one.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the measurements are in "twips".  There are 1440 twips per inch.